# Magento - xml layouts, specify value for ifconfig?

Tags: magento

I'm sure I saw before somewhere, specifying a value for xml ifconfig statements (as default is just boolean). Anyways, disabling modules in the admin doesn't actually work (only disables module output). *But* you can add an ifconfig to your layout file, so for example, to set a template only if a module is **disabled** is the following:

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="advanced/modules_disable_output/Myname_Mymodule">
    <template>mytemplate.phtml</template>
</action>
```

So how could you invert this, so the template is set only if the module is **enabled**? Something like:

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="advanced/modules_disable_output/Myname_Mymodule" value="0">
    <template>mytemplate.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Answer (score 22):

This fits in well with [something](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout) (self-link) I've been working on.

You can't do exactly what you want without a class rewrite to change the behavior of `ifconfig`.  Here's the code that implements the `ifconfig` feature.

```
File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
protected function _generateAction($node, $parent)
{
    if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

If the presence of an ifconfig is detected and the config value returns true, the action method will not be called.  You could rewrite `_generateAction` and implement your own conditional, but then the standard burdens of maintaining a rewrite fall you on.

A better approach would be to use a helper method in your action paramater.  Something like this

```
<action method="setTemplate">
    <template helper="mymodule/myhelper/switchTemplateIf"/>
</action>
```

will call setTemplate with the results of a call to

```
Mage::helper('mymodule/myhelper')->switchTemplateIf();
```

Implement your custom logic in `switchTemplateIf` that either keeps the template or changes it and you'll be good to go.

Comment: i just want to check in layout.xml to check the value of a field, which is two possible value -> top or -> below. So tho check if top is selected then show my products top of product_list either below of product_list in catalog page.. Thanx..

Comment: Can we call helper method instead of ifConfig where our custom logic return true or false.

Comment: Hi Alan, can we use this approach to set the template layout of a certain Magento page by using our own module's system variable? I've opened a new question for it. Would be glad if you could chekc it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593340/magento-changes-layout-dynamically-via-system-variable

Answer (score 10):

You could create a separate **enable** setting using nothing but your module's `system.xml`.

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <advanced>
            <groups>
                <YOURMODULE>
                    <fields>
                        <enable>
                            <label>YOUR MODULE</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enable>
                    </fields>
                </YOURMODULE>
            </groups>
        </advanced>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Then use the new setting in the layout file:

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="advanced/YOURMODULE/enable">
    <template>mytemplate.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I'm currently doing it, which does work, but just would've been nice to make use of the default module disabler, and save me having to add this to every layout.

Comment: How to check the value of that field.. => ifvalue="...."... i want to check the value of a field and then decide to show my grid on top or below of product_list...Thanks...

Comment: @ime, There is no `ifvalue` currently in the layout system, only a `ifconfig` which checks for a non-zero value. You could use that with a pair of yes/no settings, one for 'above product list' and one for 'below product list'. (That would allow the user to have both on or both off which you might not want to do.)  
The only other way is to write the PHP yourself.

Comment: Hmmm, thats ok but it if write code logic in a helper method and which return true or false value, so can i call that helper method from layout xml like ifconfig. ? which return true or false....

Comment: See Alan's answer for an example of using a helper. If you have further questions then open a new question.