# Magento Issue with using ifconfig on block

Tags: magento

I'm trying to force Magento to display a certain block only when a configuration condition is met. I was trying to use an `ifconfig` attribute on block declaration but this does not seem to work:

`<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.navigation.left.drilldown" as="left_navigation_drilldown" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left/drilldown.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/side_navigation/enabled" />
(...)
</reference>`

Sadly block is always displayed, even if `catalog/side_navigation/enabled` is set to `false`.
I've seen that it was done in the same way in `rss.xml` for rss block. Yet it does not work for me.

I was trying method with helper presented by [Alan Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601579/400437). Still no luck.

I know how to do it in way around but I would really like to use this very simple technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifconfig` will only work on an action xml element, not ony block element, here an example:

```
<reference name="footer_links">
   <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Which is sad :/ oh well, you can always make it your way by rewriting Magento class, I guess. Thanks anyways

Comment: In your case, you can still overwrite the catalog navigation block and set in the method _toHtml() the condition `if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/side_navigation/enabled')) { return;} else return parent::_toHtml();` or in the template drilldown.phtml itself

Comment: Sure, this is the way around I have mentioned in my post

Comment: Can I declare a block without template and then leverage the "setTemplate" action to implement the "ifconfig" attribute?